# How do you return created relationships using apoc.refactor.cloneNodes([nodes], true)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The signature of apoc.refactor.cloneNodes() returns

`"apoc.refactor.cloneNodes(nodes :: LIST? OF NODE?, withRelationships = false :: BOOLEAN?, skipProperties = [] :: LIST? OF STRING?) :: (input :: INTEGER?, output :: NODE?, error :: STRING?)"`

The function only yields nodes for output. Is there a way to return relationships as well, or do you have to query these manually?

My current implementation looks like this, but I thought there might be a better way?

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.id IN $ids
WITH collect(n) as nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.cloneNodes(nodes,true) yield output
MATCH (output)-[r]-()
SET output.id = apoc.create.uuid(), r.id = apoc.create.uuid()
WITH collect({source:startnode(r), edge:r, target:endnode(r) }) as edges, collect (distinct output) as nodes
RETURN *
```

search tag: `apoc.refactor.cloneNodesWithRelationships` (deprecated)

Updated to avoid cartesian products, and clarify nodesToClone and nodes:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.id in $ids
WITH collect(n) as nodesToClone
CALL apoc.refactor.cloneNodes(nodesToClone,true) yield output
SET output.id = apoc.create.uuid()
WITH output
MATCH (output)-[r]-()
SET r.id = apoc.create.uuid()
WITH collect({source:startnode(r), edge:r, target:endnode(r) }) as edges, collect (distinct output) as nodes
RETURN *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach looks pretty reasonable.

However, (this is a minor side issue) the query would set the `id` of an `output` multiple times if it has multiple relationships. If you want to avoid the unnecessary overhead, you can replace this:

```
...
MATCH (output)-[r]-()
SET output.id = apoc.create.uuid(), r.id = apoc.create.uuid()
...
```

with this:

```
...
SET output.id = apoc.create.uuid()
WITH output
MATCH (output)-[r]-()
SET r.id = apoc.create.uuid()
...
```

[UPDATE]

In your updated query, you can avoid using the `DISTINCT` option in `collect (distinct output)` this way:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.id in $ids
WITH COLLECT(n) AS nodesToClone
CALL apoc.refactor.cloneNodes(nodesToClone,true) YIELD output
SET output.id = apoc.create.uuid()
WITH COLLECT(output) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
MATCH (node)-[r]-()
SET r.id = apoc.create.uuid()
WITH COLLECT({source:startnode(r), edge:r, target:endnode(r) }) AS edges, nodes
RETURN *
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added a new the statement to include this and clarify nodesToClone from nodes. Do you know how I could avoid using collect distinct for nodes?

Comment: See my `UPDATE`.